# GNU make and list of objects

Tags: c, makefile

I have about 10 source files (.c) with headers (.h).
Only two source files (.c) are linked into executables (ELF) and contain the main function. Most of the files are compiled into objects (.o) and (re)used (statically linked) with the executables.

I've tried to define a generic rule to build all objects:

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

This works great for the sources compiled into objects. I don't need to worry about updating make file every time I add a new source file.

But I don't know what would be the best way to create rules for building executables?

```
exec1 : object1.o object2.o object3.o
    call the linker
exec2 : object1.o object2.o object4.o object5.o
    call the linker
```

This will work; but, whenever I'll include a new header (foo.h) I will also need remember to update the list of objects for this rule (add foo.o).

Is there any way make could automatically resolve required objects for a given target (maybe based on the included header files?) ?

Is there a better way to define the target for an executable?

Please note I can't use wildcard, since not all executables need all objects. Or could linker remove redundant objects?

Thanks!

Comment: The way you indicated for executable is fine, usually new header object would modify the the C source that are including them.

Comment: By the explicit rule for generating the code object file, is also a default GNU Make rule and other Make variant

Comment: The short answer to your specific question is no, there's no facility for make to automatically guess the objects it should be including in an executable based on the header files in the source.

Comment: actually, just create the 'dependency' files, (usually designated with a `.d` extension) the include them in the `%.o:%.c %.d` as the first line of the compile rule.   For the linker rule, first create macros, one for each executable, that list the object files used by that executable.  then `executable: &(themacro)`  and in the recipe use: `gcc -o $@ $>`  followed by the needed `-Llibrarypaths` and `-llibrarynames`.  Then all you need to do is update the `themacro` contents as files are added/subracted/renamed. one possibility is include all the objects tell the linker to drop all 'dead' code

Comment: There *might* be a way to do this. Is it the case that every new object file `foo.o` corresponds to a matching header file `foo.h`, #included in one of the other sources of the same executable?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wildcard` function to automate file list maintenance like

```
sources := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
```

You should also make a list of header files like

```
headers := $(wildcard *.h)
```

And add them to the compilation rule like

```
%.o : %.c $(headers)
```

GNU Make manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) has more information, including possible pitfalls.

Comment: The OP cannot use wildcard since not all executables need all objects. And it is not a good idea to add a dependency on all headers for each object file. Use cpp option `-MD` instead.

Comment: @blatinox You are not completely correct. Although not all objects depend on all headers, all objects must be rebuild if relevant headers changed. And then, only the relevant executable will be relinked. `-MD` is an option but it will make build much more complex. My method is very simple and works well for small projects. At least, I always work in this way

Comment: No, when you modify a header, only objects which include that header must be rebuilt. With your solution, you rebuild all objects ! It is useless, even if it works for small projects. Using `-MD` and other (`-MMD`, `-MP`,...) is not complex : you only have to add 3 lines in your Makefile and `make` and `cpp` do the job for you.

Comment: It is a question of personal opinion. I prefer a simple makefile and I do not care that sometimes I'm going to spend couple more seconds on compilation. I rarely change header files and this approach is the best for me. Let the OP to decide what is better for him.